# How can I remove scuffs from a vinyl record?

Tags: sound, audio, audio-restoration, record

So I fumbled my favorite vinyl the other day. It hit the side of my cabinet which transferred some white paint scuffs that I can't get off. I don't think there are any scratches, just surface-level paint marks. You can hear the needle hitting the scuffs when I play the record. What's a safe way to remove the scuffs so that the vinyl plays normally again?

Answer (score 1):

Pressed records, although stronger than a cut lacquer, are still susceptible to damage, especially the grooves.  So you're very well likely out of luck.  If you can hear the damage, then you do have surface the damage, because you will hear whatever the needle is tracking, both good and bad.

I believe there are cleaning solutions which can be used with microfiber cloth.  However, if you try any of those cleaning solutions and there is in fact damage underneath the paint transfer, you're only real option is to buy a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

have it professionally cleaned. alternatively search on youtube, there's crazy people pulling crazy stunts cleaning vinyl.. microscopes, powerful washing, you name it.